# data transfer rate anomaly (internet)

Tags: download, internet-connection

I tested my internet speed at speedtest.net. And go the result. .42Mbps Download and .21 Upload rate.
My classmate got the same download speed of .42Mbps but has .87Mbps upload rate.

1. Does upload rate affect the transfer rate?Because even though we got the same download speed. His transfer rate is about 100kbps downloading a movie from a torrent. And mine is only about 47kbps. Also the same torrent. And even direct download its always 47kbps.
2. Is it possible to tweak something in order to have higher transfer rates.

Other details:
Were also both using the same ISP. The same slow ISP. And it seems that he's getting the most out of his connection even if his plan is lower than mine. I just don't know why I'm a loser at this. And when I try to complain to the ISP. They say that I'm getting the minimum speed and its okay. That really sucks.
And I'm not using any router, so is he. The computer is directly connected to the internet using the modem provided by the ISP.

Comment: good question! +1

Comment: Discussion of BitTorrent transfers is AFAIK OK. Discussion of sharing copyright protected material via BitTorrent is almost certainly NOT OK. Just wanted you to make sure you were clear on that before you said something that would get your question closed and/or deleted.

Comment: I'm only asking of the transfer rate. Just made mention of bit torrent and direct-download as an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea. It's really hard to do anything but guess because your question only includes some test numbers and says nothing at all about

1. How you & your mate are connected to the Internet. Are you both using the same ISP? At the same time?
2. If you are using a router and if so what type of connection, wired or wireless you both are using. Are you using it simultaneously?
3. Whether you are both using the same hardware and application load.

The above is off the top of my head and I'm probably missing some other obvious questions.

Yes, upload can affect the download to the extent that if the computer you are recieving data from does not receive an ACK from your system then it will slow/stop sending you data. But that's mostly just a technical detail that is probably not relevant.

What usually matters the most is how much data is trying to come down the same data path. Whether that is a problem or not in your case depends on how you your mate access the Internet and you provided no info at all about that.

---

> Were also both using the same ISP. The
>   same slow ISP. .... And I'm not using any router, so is he. The computer is directly connected to the internet using the modem provided by the ISP.

Are you saying you both have your own modem? What type of modem? DSL or cable? Are you computers identical also?

No router, eh? Computer directly connected to the Internet? You both must like to live dangerously. Any possibility your system is choked with malware? You might try booting a Linux Live CD and then running your Internet speed test again. Not saying this is the problem, just speculating out loud.

Comment: I've edited my question, and added some other details, please see it.

Comment: yup, different modems. DSL. Both computers windows 7 os. 
Nope there's no spyware/malware. Even my newly formatted computer gets   
the same speed. The name of the modem is ZyXeL

Answer (score 0):

You and your classmate may with the same ISP but you may not be connected to the same equipment at the local exchange. You may be sharing resources with more people (contention).

Your PC may not be the same as your classmate, yours may have software that is using the Internet in the background - perhaps a peer-to-peer client that is sharing files.

To really compare, you'd have to take the same notebook PC to both places (preferably freshly installed, or booting from a Live-CD) and run several sets of tests at various times over several days, aggregating the results in some meaningful way.